# Retrieve new url from a get request, with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, url, parameters, get

I visit a webpage by entering the url http://www.example.com/example?date=2015-12-25

The server returns a page to my browser which has the url http://www.example.com/create?schedule=12345

My goal is to get the schedule parameter at the end of the resolved url (e.g. 12345). I intend to build my own simplified form for this website, which I can auto populate without having cross origin domain issues. But I need to reference the schedule parameter so that the server knows what schedule my newly posted form data refers to.

Is there a simple jquery or js method/approach to ask a server to tell you what the resolved url would be? I keep getting the original url back when I try methods involving jquery .get().

Answer (score 0):

Use this `var result = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);`

Comment: Thanks. It need to know though how to get the actual url back from an ajax POST submission, rather than how to slice up the url itself.